# Rearranging rows and column as axis in panda plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am having some problem on plotting with pandas.

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dbo.Access_Stat_all.csv',error_bad_lines=False, usecols=['Name','Format','Resource_ID','Number'])    
df1 = df[df['Resource_ID'] == 1224]
df1 = df1[['Format','Name','Number']]
df1 = df1.groupby(['Format','Name'], as_index=True).last()
df1 = df1.unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
df2 = df1[1:4].sum(axis=0)
df2.name = 'sum'
df2 = df1.append(df2)
print(df2)
df2.to_csv('test.csv', sep="\t")
df1.plot()
plt.show()
```

This is my output(not complete):

```
Name    Apr 2006  Apr 2007  Apr 2008  Apr 2009  Apr 2010  Apr 2011  Apr 2012  
Format                                                                         

entry        3.0       NaN       3.0       3.0       NaN       NaN       3.0   
html        15.0      12.0       9.0       3.0       2.0       NaN       0.0   
pdf         12.0       8.0      10.0       4.0       2.0       3.0       0.0   
sum         27.0      20.0      19.0       7.0       4.0       3.0       0.0
```

[This is what I get as plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgq7i.png)

As you can see this not a good way to plot I want my X-axis to be 'Name'(Which is date e.g 'Apr 2006'), Y-axis to be 'Number' and I want to plot the line for format(e.g 'pdf').

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need only [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) for transpose:

```
df1.T.plot()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can I exclude some 'Format' from it, for e.g If I only want to plot the lines for pdf and sum?

Comment: Sure, then use `df1.T[['pdf','sum']].plot()` - it is called `subset`.